# What is the correct syntax for defining filename with variables?

Tags: php, http-headers, filenames

Regarding downloading files and defining the headers, I am having trouble assigning a dynamic `filename` to my files. When using the code below :

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv");
```

A `test.csv` file is generated for download. However if I use this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename . '.csv');
```

It generates a `.php` file instead. Using this method also doesn't pass the `Content-Disposition` or `filename` to the header.

**Full code:**

```
session_start();
    $file =$_SESSION['csvf'];
    $filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
    header ( "Content-type: text/csv" );
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    print($file);
    exit ();
```

What is the correct syntax?

**EDIT**

Working Code after suggestions

```
session_start ();
$file = $_SESSION ['csvf'];
$filename =date ( "Y-m-d_H-i", time () );
header ( "Content-type: text/csv" );
header ( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename );
header ( 'Expires: 0' );
header ( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' );
header ( 'Pragma: public' );
header ( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize ( $file ) );
print ($file) ;
exit ();
```

Comment: `var_dump`  your `$filename` variable and see what it contains... you might also want to trim it for trailing `"` or `'`

Comment: Where is the actual file located ? I also see that you're using `filesize($file)` and at the same time using `$file` for `$filename`, it doesn't make to much sense to me, please clarify.

Comment: @PedroLobito Ye, grave error I removed `$file` from `$filename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the path to `example.csv` specified on your code, you need to give the full path to `$file`, i.e.:

```
$mySession = $_SESSION['csvf'];
//since $_SESSION['csvf'] contains the actual data you cannot use it for filename
$filename = date("Y-m-d_H-i",time()).".csv"; 
//write $mySession contents to file. Make sure this folder is writable
file_put_contents("/home/site/csvfolder/$filename", $mySession); 
$file = "/home/site/csvfolder/$filename";

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: What if my `$mySession` contains the data I want to print to a `CSV` file?

Comment: Because you simply cannot dump the contents of `$mySession` to the browser and expect it to understand what your trying to do. If you've doubts you can check [function.readfile.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: @b0w3rb0w3r your question if full of wrong answers, you must focus on how to achieve what you want on a practical way, make it work and move forward to the next task.

Comment: I just realised you're using `readfile()` I am using `print()`.

Comment: Are there any benefits of using one over the other?

Comment: I guess `print`can also be used to dump a file content but the correct function is `readfile`. `print`is normally used to print text.

Answer (score 0):

Try With Below code , it's work for me

```
$file =$_SESSION['csvf'];
$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time()).".csv";
header ( "Content-type: text/csv" );
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
print($file);
exit ();
```

Comment: Why would the OP try that ? where's the explanation?

Comment: @PedroLobito if you are smart PHP Coder no need any explanation to this simple changes.!! anyway thanks for your comment.

Comment: @HardikBhavsar I could answer to you but my time is kinda precious to spare it like that.

Comment: Don't need to add `.csv` in file name since content type is `csv` anyway.The problem was the `$file` inside `$filename` was generating a string too big for a name.

Comment: @b0w3rb0w3r , can you please show us $filename here? how long it is?

Comment: @HardikBhavsar `string(685) ""CHARACTER_SET_NAME    DEFAULT_COLLATE_NAME    DESCRIPTION    MAXLEN   
big5   big5_chinese_ci   Big5 Traditional Chinese   2  
dec8   dec8_swedish_ci   DEC West European   1  
cp850   cp850_general_ci   DOS West European   1  
hp8   hp8_english_ci   HP West European   1  
koi8r   koi8r_general_ci   KOI8-R Relcom Russian   1  
latin1   latin1_swedish_ci   cp1252 West European   1  
  "_2015-04-21_14-58 ` 
Shortened version from `var_dump`.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Like as follows,I am using this for me.

```
        header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);  
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
```

In place of `application/vnd.ms-excel` use your file format.It is for Microsoft Excel.

Comment: I was using `application/vnd.ms-excel` had problems so I changed to `text/csv`.

Comment: Yes use text/csv and try.

Comment: I Just test text/csv and application/csv both are working.you may use the below code for your reference. If it works for you never forget to accept it.:-)                             <?php 
 $fileName = "abc.csv";
 header("Content-Type:   test/csv; charset=utf-8");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);  //File name extension was wrong
 header("Expires: 0");
 header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 header("Cache-Control: private",false);
 echo "pravat,kumar,Sahoo";
?>

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
```

You can see more about download files with PHP here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Answer (score 0):

Below is a snippet for a .zip file with some descriptions on some information that header requires, perhaps a good practice is to get the information and some validations before writing headers. 
Another shorter example is also included,

```
// defines filename, type, path, size and a reference to file (handler)
// to set as values for file header
$filename = $survey_id . '.zip';

// define path to the file to be get file size on the next line
$filepath = [path to file]. '/' . $filename;

// used by 'Content-length'
$filesize = filesize($filepath);

// using fopen to get a file handler, 'r' for read, 'b' for binary (zip file)
$file_pointer = fopen($filepath, 'rb'); 

// check if file exists
if(is_file($filepath))
{
  // valid file?
  if($filesize && $file_pointer)
  {
      // some required header information to describe file, see [docs][1]
      header("Pragma: public");
      header("Expires: 0");
      header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
      header("Cache-Control: public");
      header("Content-Description: zip file");
      header("Content-Type: application/zip");
      header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);
      header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
      header("Content-length: " . $filesize);
      fpassthru($file_pointer); 

      // close 
      fclose($file_pointer);
    }
}
```

Also, checkout [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)(), a shorter snippet below

```
<?php
 $file = 'monkey.gif';

 if (file_exists($file)) {
   header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
   header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;    filename='.basename($file));
   header('Expires: 0');
   header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
   header('Pragma: public');
   header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
   readfile($file);
   exit;
}
```

?>

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Just escape your php properly like so:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . time() . '.export.csv');
```

This example will put a UNIX timestamp prepended to the file name. Of course you could get crazy with programmatically using variables or inbuilt php functions, but this is just the example.

Here is more of an example. This file name will be produced when running this php code.
2019-05-18-contacts-main-export-by-Garrick.csv

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . date("Y-m-d") . '-contacts-main-export-by-' . $uidName . '.csv');
```